# JSON DecodeError when pulling from API?

Tags: python, api

So I am trying to use the below code to pull IDs from an API.

```
# importing the requests library 
import requests 

# api-endpoint 
URL = "http://3.13.31.150:30005/api/actor"

# page params here 
page = "1"

# defining a params dict for the parameters to be sent to the API 
PARAMS = {'page':page} 

# Required headers
HEADERS = {'Content-Type':'application/json'}

# sending get request and saving the response as response object 
r = requests.get(url = URL, params = PARAMS, headers = HEADERS) 

if r.status_code != 200:
    # This means something went wrong.
    raise ApiError('GET /api/actor'.format(r.status_code))

# extracting data in json format and print results 
entity = r.json()['entity'];

# iterate 'entity' array of actors
for actor in entity:
    print('{} {}'.format(actor['id'], actor['fullName']))
```

In the second to last step, I keep getting the error

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value
```

and I'm not sure what to change to get it to work. Thanks!

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Do `print(r.content)` and `print(r.headers["content-type"])` before you try to decode JSON, perhaps the server is returning something else than what you expect (due to reasons like rate limiting, ...)

Comment: Thank you! It's something with my company laptop where the url is blocked by my system admin lol